# Open a new Finder Window if there is none (or just an info window) with Apple Script?

Tags: applescript, finder

No solution in Apple Script I have found to use an existing Finder window or open a new one is fail safe. Mostly it is suggested

```
tell application "Finder"
    if not (exists window 1) then
        make new Finder window
    end if
end tell
```

With this, if there is an info window open the code doesn't open a "normal" Finder window. An info window (opened e.g. by "Get Info") is a Finder window as well, and it can't handle calls like the following, which is intended for "normal" Finder windows:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set the target of the front Finder window to folder thePath
end tell
```

How do I have to script to open a new "normal" Finder window if there is no "normal" Finder window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The info window is not a Finder window in Apple Script. The condition "if not (exists window 1)..." should mention you are looking for a Finder window:

```
if not (exists Finder window 1) then
```

So you forgot to add "Finder" in front of window. In addition you can open a new Finder window when none is open or all are minimized:

```
tell application "Finder"
    if not (exists Finder window 1) or (get collapsed of the front Finder window) then
        make new Finder window
    end if
    set thePath to POSIX file /your/path/to/show
    set the target of the front Finder window to folder thePath
    activate
end tell
```